# DBLink query doesn't terminate even after it completes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, dblink, datagrip

I have a Dblink query Amazon RDS (Postgres) that execute an INSERT with rows from an Amazon Redshift cluster.
The query terminates after 15/20 minutes, if not more, but I can see that all rows are being inserted after only few minutes.
I'm running these queries via JetBrains' DataGrip.

Some other similar dblink on the same connection, terminate as expected.
The only difference I see being the size of the table, which is bigger in the first case.

All these queries are simply copying the whole table. Pretty much like this:

```sql
insert into rds_table(
  select *
  from db_link('foreign_server',
    $REDSHIFT$
      select *
      from redshift_table
    $REDSHIFT$) as table_n(...)
);
```

Where "foreign server" is my connection to Redshift.
I know that the query is completed because rds_table has the same number of rows as redshift_table.

DataGrip shows the query as still running:
[image: DataGrip screenshot]

and won't let me run other queries until I manually stop the query.
If I do so, the inserted rows remain in the database, meaning that the transaction has already committed.

Why is this happening? Is it a problem with DataGrip or with Postgres?
How can I fix it?

Is there any other better alternative to migrate data from Redshift to RDS?

Comment: Can you show the statement? How do you determine that no more actual inserts are happening? With a non-trivial statement, it could well happen that it takes a lot of processing to figure out that there will be no more result rows.

Comment: If you already can see the new rows, the transaction and hence the function must already have finished. What makes you think that the `dblink` call is still running?

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm running it on DataGrip and it shows as still running.
I have to manually terminate it to be able to run something else on the same console.
Are you suggesting that it could just be a DataGrip error and my query is fine?

Comment: That's my question. You say "it shows that it's still running". How exactly does it show that? If you cannot describe it in words, add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I've added a screenshot and few more lines to the question

Comment: Hi! I am Max from DataGrip. If it's possible please send SQL logs and IDE logs (Help - Show (SQL) Logs) to datagrip@jetbrains.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a concurrent transaction can already see the inserted data, that means that the inserting transaction and consequently the `INSERT` statement must already be finished.

If DataGrip shows the statement as still running, it is lying to you.

So this must be a DataGrip bug.